# How do I make 100 milliliters of 100mM H2O2 using 3% H2O2?

Tags: concentration

I need to make 100 milliliters of 100mM H2O2 using 3% H2O2.

Do I:

1. add X milliliters of distilled water to the 3% H2O2? How many ml?

or

2. add X milliliters of 3% H2O2 to the distilled water? How many ml?

Comment: You take a certain volume of 3% $\ce{H2O2}$ and add water until the total volume is 100 mL.  Because 3% $\ce{H2O2}$ is mostly water, the total volume will be very close to the sum of the volume of the two liquids you are mixing. How far did you get in finding the answer, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am a non-chemist and non-student. I just needed this one question answered for an old-seed germination project I am working on. All of the layman values I have found online have been specified by H2O2 percentage, and all scientific papers have been specified by mM.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is some sort of reagent solution so +/- 25% is probably no problem.

Assume density 1 g/ml for 3% solution which gives 0.03 g $\ce{H2O2}$ per ml, or 30 g $\ce{H2O2}$ per liter.

The molecular weight of $\ce{H2O2}$ is about 34 g/mol so:

$\dfrac{30}{34} \approx 1$ molar.

You want 100 mMolar which is 0.100 molar. Thus you need a 10 fold dilution.

So add 10 ml of the 3% to 90 ml water to get 100 ml of solution.

*Typically add the chemical solution to pure water.*

Comment: THANK YOU!! I can't upvote you as a non-member, but I really appreciate your help on this. I am using H2O2 to stimulate germination rates in old seeds. The scientific studies that I am using all use mM.